# Issues fitting a rectangle around dice in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I've been working on a class assignment, dice recognition and pip counting given an image of dice with OpenCV. I've got my implementation mostly correct and my program is able to count the dice in most cases. However, the boxes that I'm using to define the region of the dice aren't always being draw correctly.

So this is the image that I start with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rdYJ.jpg

And after running the program, I get this output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnNTU.png

Most of the time I get binding boxes that are skewed by 45 degrees. Also, the bottom right dice is recognized as a 3 but that's a smaller issue with some of the thresholding I perform, so not a problem here.

So the general flow of my program is as follows:
Send a black and white version of the picture to cv2.findContours. The second value it returns is a list of segments/contours:

```
_, segmented, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bwImg.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

From there I attempt to fit a rectangle around the dice using this method:

```
def fitRectangle(pyramid, bwImg, diceSize):
  #Fit and resize rectangle to predefined dice size
  rect = cv2.minAreaRect(pyramid)
  rect = (rect[0], (rect[1][0] + diceSize, rect[1][1] + diceSize), rect[2])

  floatRect = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
  intRect = np.int0(floatRect)
  bwImg = cv2.drawContours(bwImg, [intRect], 0, (255, 255, 255), -10)

  a, b, c, d = cv2.boundingRect(intRect)

  p1 = floatRect
  p2 = np.float32([[a,b], [a+c, b], [a, b+d], [a+c, b+d]])

  cv2.warpPerspective(bwImg, cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(p1, p2), p2.shape)
```

Do note, that since the boxes are roughly 3x the size of the dice as the dice are roughly a static size within all of the pictures we're testing. Since my implementation is currently rotating the box by 45 degrees, I increase the size of the box to fit the entire dice. If I don't, I get results like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jLoo.png

At this point, I'm pretty stuck. I'm not sure what's causing this rotation in the rectangles I'm fitting and it's causing some pretty wonky results in some of my other tests where boxes that touch merge into a single region:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDjmg.png

If you have any ideas what might be the culprit here any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:
I realized it might be important to include all of my contouring code:

```
def getContours(segmented, original, bwImg, diceSize, bwThreshold):
#Capture small contours
_, segmented, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bwImg.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Fit rectangle onto pyramid
for pyramid in segmented:
    fitRectangle(pyramid, bwImg, diceSize * 3)

#Capture large contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bwImg.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#contours = segmented   
#Get pips based on beThreshold
pips = 255 - cv2.threshold(original, bwThreshold, 255, 1)[1]

#Get only pips without dice
onlypips = cv2.bitwise_and(bwImg, pips)
dice = cv2.cvtColor(onlypips, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

errorDice = 0
results = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

#Count pips in each die
for contour in contours:    
    pips, a, b = getNumPips(contour, onlypips)

    #print (pips)
    #If a die has more than 6 or less than 0 pips it is not a valid die
    if pips > 6 or pips == 0:
        errorDice += 1
    else:
        results[pips - 1] = results[pips - 1] + 1
        cv2.putText(dice,str(pips),(a,b-5),0,10,(255,255,255), 25)      

return contours, dice, errorDice, results
```

Comment: What does your binarized image that you start with look like?